# KeyTrigger passing parameters

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, triggers

I have a textbox and want to pass text entered in command. I do follwong:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <iex:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextBoxMessageCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </iex:KeyTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

Code in Command:

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       string msg = parameter;
```

It's OK. Method Execute fires properly and nice. But parameter == null.
What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to give a name to your `TextBox` and reference it via this name in the command. Self won't work from within a command.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <iex:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextBoxMessageCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=textbox}"/>
            </iex:KeyTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This thing is working well. May be another way exists to. I mean.. more elegant..

Comment: Maybe `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textbox}"`, then you can cast the parameter to a `TextBox`, and use or clear the `Text` property.

Comment: Yes - that great. But I need to scroll down my chat message List after command firing. I can't pass two parameters !